# Error creating application in Spinnaker on kubernetes : "Could not create application: No message available"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, spinnaker, kubernetes-helm

I have installed spinnaker on k8s using Helm :

```
 helm install --name spinnaker-release stable/spinnaker -f spinnaker-config.yaml --timeout 800 --namespace kube-system --debug
```

Got an error back from spinnaker installation:

```
 Error: transport closed
```

But when looked for spinnaker associated pods , everything is with status Running:

[image]

[image]

Please find below the error logs from front50:

```
    2018-02-28 02:44:36.167 ERROR 1 --- [pplicationDAO-7] c.n.s.front50.model.GcsStorageService    : Failed to load applications sampleapp: 404 Not Found
    2018-02-28 02:44:36.518 ERROR 1 --- [pplicationDAO-8] c.n.s.front50.model.GcsStorageService    : Failed to load applications sampleapp: 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without the config file. Can you share?

This one worked for me: https://github.com/moondev/spinnaker-helm

Note: dollar sign ($) is missing to the command for port forwarding. Should be:

```
kubectl --namespace spinnaker port-forward $(kubectl --namespace spinnaker get pods -l app=deck -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}') 9000:9000
```